# StackPanel disappears on physical device but is visible in Simulator

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I've created an sidebar with images using StackPanel WPF control. I've set simulator to 23'' and 1920x1080, the device is 42'' and resolution is 1920x1080 too. In simulator the StackPanel is visible, on the device is not.

XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Height="1080" Margin="0,0,300,0" VerticalAligment="Top" Margin="1620,0,0,0"/>
...rest of StackPanel XAML code...
```

Why is so? Why it dissapears?

Comment: try removing Margin="1620,0,0,0"...why there is two Margin="0,0,300,0" and Margin="1620,0,0,0...there must be xaml error

Comment: It maked StackPanel to cover whole screen

Comment: to cover whole screen you need to use grid panel instead of stackpanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you may need to use some other techniques to align to right as specifying margin, width etc properties may get calculated differently on different devices

read more at [DPI and Device-Independent Pixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173)

you may try

```
<StackPanel Height="1080" VerticalAligment="Top" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

perhaps a better approach would be using a Grid to align properly

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--your content-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

you may also choose to define the size units i.e. inch to keep the size uniform on various devices

eg

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2in" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--your content-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

so this will ensure that the stack panel is always 2 inch on every device

Comment: I am glad it worked for you, you may also experiment with the other approach I mentioned in the answer too to see what benefits they bring to you.